# intergration between limits

Tags: calculus, integration

So during lecture there was this problem that was worked through and i understand it right up until the very end, and i was wondering if someone could explain how he simplified it down.

So there was a double integration, and once it had been integrated twice it came out as

$$R^2(2\pi)(-1/a)e^{a\cos\theta} \text{( this is already integrated)} $$

it had been integrated with respect to $\theta$ and it now all i have to do was sub in $\pi$ as the upper limit and $0$ as the lower limit

it came out as $2\pi a(e^{-a}-e^a)$
and im not quite sure how

Comment: We're not sure how either since we don't see the integral. See the help pages about MathJax. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/171839

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result as you substitute in $0$ and $\pi$ for $\theta$ is as follows:

\begin{align}
R^2 (2 \pi) \left( - \frac1a\right)\left[ \exp(a \cos\theta) \right]_0^\pi &= R^2 (2 \pi) \left( - \frac1a\right) \left[\exp(a \cos\pi) - \exp(a \cos 0)  \right]\\
&= R^2 (2 \pi) \left( - \frac1a\right) \left[\exp(a (-1)) - \exp(a (1))  \right]\\
&= R^2 (2 \pi) \left( - \frac1a\right) \left[\exp(-a) - \exp(a)  \right]\\
\end{align}

You mentioned that it is a double integration, but it seems that you have not integrated with $R$ or is $R$ a constant. With the information that is given, there is no way to explain away the $R$ term unless $R$ is somehow equal to $a$ and the negative sign is just  a typo.

Comment: Perhaps a negative sign was mistakenly omitted when copying the "it came out as" formula into the question on this page.

Comment: thank you very much, so i believe the R^2 is a constant so i will email my lecturer about that thank you, and i put the exponentials in the bracket in the wrong order which explains the minus sign i believe